# Set product tax in Magento observer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I'm using `sales_quote_add_item` and I'd like to change the tax class of a product.
In observer, I retrieve product:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$item = $event->getQuoteItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
```

I tried  `$item->setTaxClassId()` and `$product->setTaxClassId()` methods but this didn't work.

Any other approaches available?

Comment: in which event you are working now?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change `product_tax_class` using `observer` then you have to use `sales_quote_item_set_product`.

The function `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::setProduct` resets some of the basic information each time a product is saved

```
config.xml

<config>
...
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_item_set_product>
                <observers>
                    <samples>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>samples/observer</class>
                        <method>salesQuoteItemSetProduct</method>
                    </samples>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_item_set_product>
        </events>
    <global>
...
</config>

Observer.php

class Mynamespace_Samples_Model_Observer
{
    public function salesQuoteItemSetProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

        $item->setTaxClassId('2');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: This does not change tax class for product added to cart unfortunately.

Comment: I tried it in the sales_quote_item_set_product event as you explained in your answer.

Comment: accept the answer if you find helpful @GerarddeVisser

Comment: @KeyurShah, how to set custom tax amount here instead of tax tax id? for the specific quote item

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$item->setTaxClassId()` and `$product->setTaxClassId()`
try

`$item->getProduct()->setTaxClassId()`

Comment: I did already try this as you can read in my question, but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry missed it!
Did you try it in the observer sales_quote_collect_totals_before?

Comment: Also try the code  `$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) { $item->getProduct()->setTaxClassId(); }`

Comment: @John, how to set fixed tax amount for quote item?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Sorry! No idea, been a while since I've worked on Magento!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this.

I was developing GST module as India has changed our taxation system.

Go to your custom module and add below event observer in config.xml

```
<events>    
   <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
       <observers>
           <sales_quote_add_item_handler>
               <type>model</type>
               <class>gst/observer</class>
               <method>checkTax</method>
           </sales_quote_add_item_handler>
       </observers>
   </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
</events>
```

Now in your module's Model folder create Observer.php and add below function into it.

```
public function checkTax(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $quote_item) {
        $product = $quote_item->getProduct();
        $product->setTaxClassId(2);
        $quote_item->setPriceInclTax($quote_item->getPrice());
        $quote_item->setBasePriceInclTax($quote_item->getBasePrice());
        $quote_item->setBaseRowTotalInclTax($quote_item->setBaseRowTotal());
    }
    $quote->save();
}
```

Hope this will help you out :)